# Terrain Generation - Diamond Square Algorithm

Tags: java, procedural-generation, maps

I'm trying to implement a Map Generator in Java. Since it´s said to be simple I wanted to use the Diamond Square Algorithm [2D] for that purpose.

However, I can´t find any complete understandable description of the algorithm, so I am using ~4 different sites (eg. [this one from grubz](http://gru.bz/2012/10/diamond-square-algorithm-help/)) to build it, and on some sites things are described differently than on others.

As far as I understand it, the algorithm works as follows:

- generate a map with random values (just setting every x,y of the map)
- make square step
- make diamond step
- begin with square again

The map size is defined by a "step". That step will be

```
step =Math.pow(2,step)+1
```

which denotes the width and height of the map. This means if I want a map with ~300 tiles I will have to provide `step = 9` - but on other sites it´s written that the step is only changing the "smoothness". What is it?

-square step
I begin at halfStep (x/y), take the surrounding "square" Points and average those.

-diamond step: Same as above but I begin halfStep earlier.

[Here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/POHLYTQFFQ) is what I did so far. Not working due to an ArrayError.

**Question:**

How do I control how big the map is gonna be? (I assume step?).

How do I control here what the output map looks like? eg.: to generate island/continents/deserts/half-islands/ how would I get one big Continent at the center/thick jungles etc. (I have seen something like scale, scaleMod, etc)

Is my Code correct according to the algorithm? I just don´t get it exactly.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but a question: is your goal to learn diamond-square or is your goal to make a map generator? if your goal is to make a map generator, I recommend using a simplex/perlin library so that you can skip the diamond-square code entirely.

Comment: I'd second amitp here. Diamond-Square is well suited to generating uniformly noisy terrain, like a basic fractal mountainscape, but the contrasts described in your question (islands, deserts, continents, jungles) don't lend themselves naturally to the tuning knobs we have with diamond-square. You may be more in the territory of noise-based methods - [amitp wrote an excellent introduction here](http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/), and [this article has some neat ideas about sculpting noise for different terrain features](http://www.decarpentier.nl/scape-procedural-extensions).

Comment: As I understand it, to set the size of the map you start at the corners of a large square (the size of the map), seed the heights, and work inwards using the diamond square algorithm, creating a random earth-like terrain between those seeded points. To create one big continent at the center you could seed the edges of the map with a low value that could represent terrain underwater and bias the offset to increase the height as points approach the center, creating some sort of island continent.